# Pandas update column conditionally if another column exists

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a dataframe with a column whose value depends on the existence of another column, so I tried to use `np.where` to condition the value like this:

```
the_dataframe["dependant_value"] = np.where(
    "independant_value_" + the_dataframe["suffix"].str.lower()
    in the_dataframe.columns,
    the_dataframe["another_column"]
    * the_dataframe[
        "independent_value_" + the_dataframe["suffix"].str.lower()
    ],
    0,
)
```

But I'm getting this error:

```
 File "C:\the_file.py", line 271, in the_method
    "independent_value_" + the_dataframe["suffix"].str.lower()
  File "C:\the_file.py", line 4572, in __contains__
    hash(key)
TypeError: unhashable type: 'Series'
```

I suppose there must be a propper way to make the logic evaluation of the condition, but I haven't found it.

Comment: What do you mean by using `Series in the_dataframe.columns`? There is `Series.isin` method.

Comment: @Ynjxsjmh the first argument of `np.where` is the condition, the second argument is the option when the condition is `True` and the third argument is the option when the condition is `False`

Comment: Can you provide a minimal sample of your df and expected output?

Comment: Ignore my previous deleted comment, I take it as `np.select` somehow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no syntax like `Series in Series/Index`

```
$ s = pd.Series([1, 2])
$ s in s

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "~/sourcecode/test/so/73460893.py", line 44, in <module>
    s in s
  File "~/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py", line 1994, in __contains__
    return key in self._info_axis
  File "~/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/range.py", line 365, in __contains__
    hash(key)
TypeError: unhashable type: 'Series'
```

You might want `Series.isin`

```py
    ("independant_value_" + the_dataframe["suffix"].str.lower()).isin(the_dataframe.columns),
```

Comment: I was so close, only failed to wrap the first part of the sentence between parenthesis